# How to reliably check if IndexedDB transaction is active?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm trying to implement a simple IndexedDB manager that would create a new transaction under the hood whenever necessary, with the idea to have a simpler interface. Currently I'm treating transaction's `oncomplete` callback as an indicator that the transaction can't be used anymore and then I'm creating a new transaction at the beginning of any `get`, `add`, `put`, etc. method of the manager. This approach seems to work for me most of the times but it can sometimes throw an exception due to the transaction being inactive.

I created an example that reproduces the problem here: https://plnkr.co/edit/W3TaPymAmc7R8BFL?preview (also copied at the end of question). I have an `input` event listener attached to the input field and I'm saving its current value to IndexedDB. When I type really fast in the field it will sometimes throw an exception in the console and not save the last value. For example, this is what i see in the console after pressing `1` and `2` at the same time.

```json
dbManager.js:56 put 1
dbManager.js:47 Ensuring the store is valid
dbManager.js:18 Generating new store
dbManager.js:56 put 12
dbManager.js:47 Ensuring the store is valid
dbManager.js:67 put - catch 12
dbManager.js:60 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': The transaction is not active.
                  at (...)/lib/dbManager.js:60:44
                  at new Promise (\<anonymous\>)
                  at MyStore.put ((...)/lib/dbManager.js:58:16)
                  at HTMLInputElement.putData ((...)/lib/script.js:5:11)
dbManager.js:62 put - onsuccess 1
dbManager.js:27 Transaction completed
```

As you can see, the `transaction is not active` exception was thrown before the transaction's `oncompleted` actually fired. This happens in all browsers that I tested (Chrome, Opera, Edge and Firefox).

How should I approach this problem? Is there some other way that I can detect if the transaction is active? One workaround that comes to my mind is pushing requests into a FIFO queue and executing them in order while awaiting for each request to complete but that will probably just result in having to create a separate transaction for each request.

Code from plunkr:

lib/dbManager.js

```js
class MyIndexedDb {
    async connect(name, upgrade, version) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const request = indexedDB.open(name, version);
            request.onupgradeneeded = (e) => upgrade(request.result, e);
            request.onsuccess = () => {
                this.database = request.result;
                this.database.onerror = (e) => console.error(e);
                resolve();
            };
            request.onerror = () => reject(request.error);
        });
    }


    getStore = (storeName, mode) => {
        const idbStore = new MyStore(() => {
            console.log("Generating new store");
            if (!this.database) {
                throw ("Database is not defined.");
            }

            const transaction = this.database.transaction(storeName, mode);
            const store = transaction.objectStore(storeName);

            transaction.oncomplete = () => {
                console.log("Transaction completed");
                idbStore.invalidateTransaction();
            }
            return store;
        });
        return idbStore;
    }
}

class MyStore {
    constructor(storeGenerator) {
        this.storeGenerator = storeGenerator;
        this.shouldRegenerateStore = true;
    }

    invalidateTransaction = () => {
        this.shouldRegenerateStore = true;
    }

    ensureValidStore = () => {
        console.log("Ensuring the store is valid");
        if (!this.shouldRegenerateStore) {
            return;
        }
        this.shouldRegenerateStore = false;
        this.store = this.storeGenerator();
    }

    put = async (key, value) => {
        console.log("put", value);
        this.ensureValidStore();
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const request = this.store.put(value, key);
                request.onsuccess = () => {
                    console.log("put - onsuccess", value);
                    return resolve(request.result);
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log("put - catch", value);
                reject(e);
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

lib/script.js

```js
let store, input;

function putData() {
  try {
    store.put("key", input.value);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

function upgradeDb(db) {
    db.createObjectStore("store");
}

async function load() {
  const idb = new MyIndexedDb();
  try {
      await idb.connect("db", upgradeDb);
  } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      return;
  }

  store = idb.getStore("store", "readwrite");

  input = document.getElementById("input");
  input.addEventListener("input", putData);
}

load();
```

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script defer src="lib/dbManager.js"></script>
    <script defer src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="input"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions have multiple states. They are *active* in the task in which they are created (e.g. the button click handler that eventually calls `db.transaction()`), and in the tasks for `success`/`error` events from requests made against the transaction. In between those tasks (i.e. some random setTimeout() callback, a different click handler, etc) they are *inactive*. That's likely what you're running into - you can only issue new requests in a callback from a previous request; otherwise you'll see that error.

Once a transaction has no more requests -- it has transitioned from *active* - as a result of a callback - back to *inactive* and no new requests were made - then it enters a *committing* state where it tries to commit. It's also not active, so this is another place you can get that error. Only after the commit succeeds or fails does the transaction enter a *finished* state and `abort` or `complete` events fire.

Comment: So is there a way to check whether the request will be executed in the same task it was created on from inside of dbManager, if I have no knowledge of how and when it will be invoked? Maybe something like `let sameTask = true; setTimeout(() => sameTask = false);`? But I don't know if that would be reliable.

Comment: You simply can't create a transaction (in the `getStore()` call) and use it at an arbitrarily later time (the `putData()` call in your event handler) - the transaction will have gone inactive and tried to commit. It'll never work. With your current code structure, you'll need to call getStore() and putData() within the same event handler, i.e. create a transaction and use it within the same task.